# How to keep a checkbox value to reuse it later in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, data-validation

I'm working on a Google sheet actually (only for fun) and I'm actually stuck on something, as I said in the title, I want to keep a checkbox value in Google sheet.

I will explain my problem.

I'm doing a sheet of some information who will appear when I change the value of a dropdown list. But I want to be able to check a checkbox in one Dropdown item and when I change this item, have the checkbox who will take the value of the other item. A little example:

I have 2 dropdown item: one called poney and the other called horse, I check the checkbox while I was in poney and I change to the horse. I want the checkbox value go to false and when I go back to poney the checkbox retake the value true

EDIT: I add a Google sheet example on how I use it: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ySbHJJohneH_2hS3_lhl2Va-U4ejan-jeW0btbaMGlw/edit?usp=sharing

I hope someone can help me with that!

Comment: so you want to switch off the checkbox by switching on the other one??

Comment: Yeah, and keep the value for, when i go back on the first one, the checkbox is checked

Comment: Reading your comments to one of the answer it looks that you need to use Google Apps Script and on edit trigger. Please update your question or post a new one to clarify what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(B2="poney", TRUE, 
 IF(B2="horse", FALSE))
```

[image: 0]

**[demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10NB1v0oFfcKFYv3sQnK62RTO1QW6yn3vDc_Z9TSttRU/copy)**

---

- let **A1** cell be a checkbox with the formula: **`=IF(B1=FALSE; TRUE; FALSE)`**
- let **B1** cell be a regular checkbox with logic **`TRUE`**/**`FALSE`**
- let **D1** cell be an auxiliary formula which you can hide: **`=IF(A1=TRUE; FALSE; TRUE)`**

  [image: 0]
- **[demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i0LMUEfv1M-hc-waUBCFLWBK8sR4Jbb7j9F9P0dvOJM/copy)**

Comment: Ok i see, it's like a stamp mémorie, but it didn't work for what i want to do, when i'm back on the first item, it take the value of the second

Comment: @Sora answer updated

Comment: Ok, but i can't check it or uncheck it directly, and it wont be saved in the other page i would it be. But it's kind what i want.

Do you know how can i make it checkable and how to saved it on the other page ?

Like below  "this is the formula ..." In the second page. I want to be able to do "(=IF(B2="poney", "Data!A3",
IF(B2="horse", "Data!B3))

Comment: Sad story so, thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

In Google Sheets, check boxes are a visual aids or cells that allow one of two values. The default values are true and false but they could be customized. You could put a formula that that return one of the other of this two values, maybe the simple examples are the logic operator functions AND and OR and the IF function.

1. Add the formula to the cell
2. Add a data validation, select the display as checkbox option and if required set the two valid values.

Comment: You mean, replace the value"true" by something like : =if (Data!A1 = true, A1=true, A1=false)?